# Does Google Apps block code from the Chrome console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I noticed the Chrome console gave an error when the following was typed:

```
$("body").hide();
```

Is there a solution to modify HTML elements when working with Google Apps?

[image: Google Sheets]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery can't be accessible in browser console directly, because it's a external library file & doesn't come inbuilt within browser.

So to access the Jquery from console, you can run below line in console;

```
var jqlib = document.createElement('script');
jqlib.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jqlib);
```

Here we get the script tag of current page & injecting JQuery library into it.

After running above lines, you can execute your code;

```
$(body).hide();
```

Comment: Additional note: Google Apps have nothing to do here. As per exception, that you posted, it's jQuery which is not recognized in console.

Comment: Would I also need to find a way to access jQuery if a script is added through the Elements tab?

Image example: [Image Link](https://ibb.co/gWSzw5)